# Nitrogen - File upload directly to database

Tags: erlang, riak, nitrogen

In the [Nitrogen Web framework](http://nitrogenproject.com/), files uploaded always end in the `./scratch/` directory when using `#upload{}`. From here you are supposed to manage the uploaded files, for example, by copying them to their final destination directory.

However, in case the destination is a database, is there a way of uploading these files straight to the database? Use case **RIAK-KV**.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a file to Riak KV using an HTTP POST request. You can see the details at in the [Creating Objects documentation](https://www.tiot.jp/riak-docs/riak/kv/latest/developing/usage/creating-objects/) which shows how to do it using `curl`.

To send the contents of a file instead of a value, something like this should work:

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:8098/types/default/buckets/scratch/keys/newkey
-d @path/to/scratch.file
-H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
```